# What Punctuation mark should I use to answer a question

Tags: grammar

What’s the making or breaking factor? –an understanding teacher vs. one who likes to eat souls for fun.

This is part of a speech that i am currently writing (I'm a gr. 11 student btw)

Answer (score 1):

Follow your manual of style, either the one you've selected or the one thrust upon you.  I use *The Chicago Manual of Style*, which directs the question mark to the end of the interrogatory element.  Thus:

"What's the making or breaking factor -- an understanding teacher vs. one who likes to eat souls for fun?

As a rhetorical device, you may repeat your question with the appositive choice, thus:

"What's the making or breaking factor?  An understanding teacher vs. one who likes to eat souls for fun?

Comment: A third option is to use a colon: "What's the making or breaking factor: an understanding teacher vs. one who likes to eat souls for fun?"

Comment: @Araucaria Done.

Comment: @deadrat Thanks, old bean. (Hope we're on first legume terms now ;))

Comment: @Araucaria You're welcome. Indeed, you're my fava-right correspondent here.